# position:absolute !important does not work in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, position, absolute

[My Site](http://myscholly.com/iphone.php)

My problem: In all other browsers, I can position my slideshow absolutely to appear within a frame. However in Firefox the page renders and Firefox automatically puts the slideshow as `position: relative`.

What the code should be:

```
top: 95px; left: 22px; position: absolute !important;
```

What it is:

```
position: relative; top: 95px; left: 22px;
```

Why doesn't Firefox support `position: absolute` in this case?

Comment: Your page looks broken in IE9, html 4.01 transitional .. with a couple of errors ..

Comment: Looks like the slideshow script is assigning `position:relative`...not sure why it only does it (or why it only impacts the page) in FF.

Comment: exactly how do you set the style in fadeshow1?

Comment: I see in your site `setting.$wrapperdiv=$('#'+setting.wrapperid).css({position:'relative'` after which, in chrome the position is still absolute, while in firefox it is relative, could this have something to do with this?

Comment: yes, in `js/fadeslideshow.js`, line: 48, `setting.$wrapperdiv=$('#'+setting.wrapperid).css({position:'relative', visibility:'visible'....` try changing position value with `absolute`

Comment: @Ejay YUP! That was it. Still weird that FF didn't recognize the inline. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CSS file, specifying `position: absoulte !important` for `#fadeshow1` *might* work

```
#fadeshow1{position: absolute !important}
```

Also,  in `js/fadeslideshow.js`, line: 48, `setting.$wrapperdiv=$('#'+setting.wrapperid).css({position:'relative', visibility:'visible'....` try changing position value with `absolute`

Answer (score 0):

That is strange. But, take out the !important.